# ABCPdf Microsoft XPS printer

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xps, printers, abcpdf

I'm using ABCPdf get a pdf from a some HTML code. While I was developing everything worked great, now I install it in the server it is not working. It throw this exception

> WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.PDFException:
>   ABCpdf cannot detect any printers.
>   Gecko Engine requires a printer
>   installed in the system. Usually, XPS
>   Document Writer would suffice. Try
>   also running the service as an
>   interactive user.

In my computer I have MS office installed, in the server I don't.

So my questions are:

- Is there anyway (with ABCpdf) to generate a PDF using Doc.AddImageHtml method without the MS XPS printer?
- If not, is there anyway I can install the XPS printer without installing the office?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if I change to use MSHtml Engine to render the HTML I have no problem in the server.

[This rendering engine does not work with IE9 + .NET framework 4 + ASP.NET and not web forms. (That is actually my case). Luckily the server has Windows Server 2003, so it doesn't have IE9.](http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm) Please note that in the link you should go to  section

> ABCpdf

and then to the question

> 6.29 - Converting HTML with IE9 installed, I see the exception:
>   'ABCpdf could not initiate MSHtml
>   engine for this version of Internet
>   Explorer installed.'

This is the only solution I have right now but if someone has a solution that make ABCPdf work without Microsoft XPS Printer and has no trouble with IE9 it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Recent version of ABCpdf has lifted the requirement of a printer for the Gecko engine, and IE9 support for MSHtml should _just work_ now. (Full disclosure: blah blah blah ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the XPS Essentials Pack for server 2003, which includes the XPS driver from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11816

If your server is 2000 then it won't work however the error message hints any driver will work. Open the Printers folder and from the File menu select Server Properties, go t the Drivers tab and add any PostScript driver. I'm guessing the component is relying on having a printer driver installed to get font widths.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Windows and .NET will have XPS Document Writer automatically. You may try reinstalling it: http://forums.techarena.in/vista-help/782555.htm